# iOS: animation with four button rounded

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, ios7, xcode5

Any one have idea about this kind of animation.above image have four button animated rounded.
thanks for advance.

[image]

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/cyndibaby905/TumblrMenu

Comment: See this one https://github.com/levey/AwesomeMenu

Comment: @AnjDenny sorry both are demo not useful for this.

Comment: Edit the code will work fine

Comment: it's very complicated.i was seen.

Answer (score -2):

here is the similar animation,
http://code4app.net/ios/AAShareBubbles/52a6b36dcb7e840d158b5f4f